# How to show $T=\{\forall x(x\neq S^{n}x)|1\leq n\}\cup\{\sigma\}$ in $\mathcal{L}=\{S\}$ is $\kappa$-categorical

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Problem saying:

Let $T=\{\forall x(x\neq S^{n}x)|1\leq n\}\cup\{\sigma\}$
  in $\mathcal{L}=\{S\}$
 , where $S$
  is a unary function and $S^{n}$
  abbreviates $\underbrace{S\dots S}_{n}$
 , and $\sigma$
  is a sentence saying that $S$
  is bijective.Show that $T$  is complete.

So, I tried to do so by using Los-Vaught Test. So, I want to show that

1) $T  $ is consistent(satisfiable) and

2) If is $\kappa$-categorical for some infinite cardinal larger  than $Card(\mathcal L)$.

So, I show 1) with model $M=(\mathbb N,S)$ where S is a successor function. Then $M\models T$.

Thus, I have to show that it is $\kappa$-categorical for some cardinal $\kappa$.

But How can I?

edit) In my model, S is not bijective. So, I also fail to show that T is consistent.

Comment: But $S$ is not bijective in the model you gave.

Comment: Ah! There's no predecessor of 0. I see what you're saying....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To repair your consistency proof, replace $\mathbb N$ with $\mathbb Z$. To prove categoricity in all uncountable powers, show that any model of $T$ is a disjoint union of some isomorphic copies of the $\mathbb Z$ example.  If the model has uncountable cardinality $\kappa$, then there have to be exactly $\kappa$ copies, so the model is unique up to isomorphism.  ($T$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical, because the number of copies of $\mathbb Z$ in a countably infinite model of $T$ can be any positive integer or $\aleph_0$.)  By the way, to finish the proof of completeness, you also have to check that $T$ has no finite models, but that's pretty easy.

Comment: An entirely different way to prove completeness of $T$ is via quantifier elimination.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what "isomorphic copies" mean?

Comment: An isomorphic copy of one structure $A$ in another structure $B$ is a substructure of $B$ that is isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: Since a model N of T contains  natural number $\omega$, $|N|\geq \aleph _0$  Then for a remaining element a, make its chain. And for  another remaining element b, make its chain. a's  chain doesn't contain b and b's chain doesn't contain a. So, I can this procedure $|N|$ many times. So, T is not $\aleph_0$ -categorical. (It seems to be wrong. There could be a model with cardinality $\aleph_0$)

Comment: Is it correct understanding what you said?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "It could be wrong. There could be a model with cardinality $\aleph_0$." There are, as I wrote in my answer, infinitely many different (i.e., non-isomorphic) models of cardinality $\aleph_0$, and therefore $T$ is not $\aleph_0$-categorical.  What is the "It" that could be wrong?

Comment: If $|N|=\aleph_0$, I could only do that procedure countably many times. So, It seems to be that I have to show that $N$  and $M=(\mathbb Z,0,S)$ are not isomorphic.